# CC3D - Replacing RC emitter with an RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, quadcopter, uav

I am trying to control a quadcopter using te OpenPilot CC3D board and a RaspberryPi. The main idea was first replace the signals from the RC emitter to the CC3D RC receiver for an RPi connected directly to the RC receiver inputs of the CC3D.

As far as I know the RC signals to the CC3D are PWM so the RPi should be able to control the channels using RPIO library to create the PWM by software.

But after make some tests I haven't find any way to move the motors. I am using the Ground Control System (OpenPilot Software) to configure the CC3D.

I am not sure whether I need to send the PWM signals in any order or something like that. I am also not sure how the Flight Mode Switch works, I suposse it works the same way as the other channels, using PWM.

Anyone have made anything similar to this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but I don't know at all how to plug the 8 cables from the CC3D receiver to the GPIO of my RPi, could you give me some help on that please ?

Comment: Hi could u help me I want to do exactly the same but it doesnt work for me over pwm. So what did you do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally control the CC3D from the RPi.

The problem was a bad configuration from a RC input.
I also upgrade the CC3D firmware from the new Groung Control System software developed by LibrePilot, another community that wants to give support for the OpenPilot boards.

Comment: hi osuarez ,i m desperate need of a tutorial how to do it , i have arduino , raspberry pi and cc3d ,  can you pls tell me how did you do it...

Comment: This is a 2 year old post, but how did you do this? Can you link to any code or wiring diagrams?